# Matching different object in 2 sets

Tags: java, set, matching

I need a pattern that matches 2 sets of objects, A and B. The 2 objects are of different types.

2 objects are matched when 3 of their members match. 2 matching objects can have members that are different.

The processing is as follows:

Find a matching object from B in A.
Check the value of member variable X in the matcing objects.
If X is different, add the matched object to a 'modified' set and
Replace matched object in A with matched object from B.

The number of objects in A and B should be equal. If not, I should end the processing. Basically, B is a potential update of A. If there are updates, I need a new A (New A) and a list of the objects in B that were different from A (Modified).

I have tried looping through both lists and matching using CollectionUtils.select but I wonder is there a cleaner solution.

E.g. (for brevity, 2 objects match if Ref is the same)

```
A

Ref     x
abc1    100
abc2    200
abc3    300
abc4    400

B

Ref     x
abc1    700
abc2    200
abc3    600
abc4    400
abc5    500

Result:

Modified
abc1    700
abc3    600

New A
abc1    700
abc2    200
abc3    600
abc4    400
```

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: @Prashant - I have tried looping through both lists and matching using CollectionUtils.select but I wonder is there a cleaner solution.

Comment: you can iterate over list B and check in list A. if list A contains the element currently iterating get the element from A and modify.

Comment: edit ur question and add ur codes to it

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a method that takes  two objects as aparameters (1 type a , other type b ) and returns a boolean (match or not)
Based on your example classes (members are ref and x , but match if only ref is the same)
Example :

```
 boolean match (A a , B b){
  return (ref.equals(b.ref));
}
```

You could iterate through the lists and compare As and Bs and whenever the method returns true , add B in modified and whenever returns false add A in new. 
Hope it helps